# Data size: df and e2fsck discrepancy

Tags: raspbian

I have been making dd backup images of my 32 GB Rpi sdcard and then using a shrink script (involving resize2fs) to reduce the image size (to data size plus a bit more). Until a while ago the images used to shrink from 32 GiB to around 8.5 GB but recently they started only going down to 11.5 GB. Using df -h I still see 8.5 GB used, but mounting an image and running e2fsck shows e.g. 2443706/7724160 blocks which works out to the 11 (odd) GB. Can anyone suggest where I should start looking for the other 3 GB?

Comment: Look in logs, look in apt cache. `cd /var/log; sudo rm -rf *.gz` and `sudo apt autoclean`

Comment: Thanks. I had done those things. What is puzzling me is why the file usage shown by `df` differs from the used block count given by e2fsk, when previously it didn't.

Comment: Then you're going to have to start scanning the filesystem to find the largest files and largest folders containing stuff.

Comment: don't bother searching for files as others have suggested ... you can see exactly how much of the disk is in use using df as you have done - looking for 3GB of files that aren't there is leasing you along the wrong path - there's only 8.5GB in use, there are no files taking up another 3GB, otherwise df would report 11.5GB in use - seems obvious

Comment: exactly how are you running resize2fs